# USA ESTA - Changed my address but point of contact can’t be changed and now differs?

Tags: usa, esta

I thought I was staying in a hotel and applied for an ESTA based on that. The hotel was both my ‘point of contact’ and my address where I would be staying in the US. The ESTA was approved.

My hotel has now changed. I edited my ESTA to include my new address where I would be staying. But I can’t edit my point of contact (previous hotel). So now my ESTA now shows a hotel I’m not staying at as my point of contact.

Is this a problem?

Comment: Shouldn't be a problem., plans change. An ESTA authorisation is valid for 2 years and multiple entries and you're unlikely to stay in exactly the same hotel for multiple trips over that time anyway